# Unity 5.6.2f1 + Cardboard SDK: Unable to look around + screen is tilted

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

After I upgraded to Unity 5.6.2f1 and I can't get google cardboard vr to work properly. Every project I build onto Android/iOS, I cannot look around (frames are running but I have no control of the camera to look around) and my camera is tilted right from the start of game. I imported gvr sdk and turned on vr support.  I spent the past few hours trying to figure this out but no luck. Any ideas?

This is a screenshot of my build from my phone.  Screen is fixed and slanted for some reason.  Head tracking does not work.
[image]

This is not a code issue.  I believe the problem lies with compatibility between Unity 5.6's native VR and Google VR SDK.  With any VR supported Android or iOS build, my picture is slightly tilted and screen is fixed (as in I am unable to look around/have my camera rotate with my phone).  I tried gvr's demo scenes and its the same problem.

Comment: Edited to specify this is an issue between 5.6 and Google SDK.  Not sure why native vr isn't working properly.

Comment: Does your phone have a Gyro? i upgraded to 5.6.2f1 today and have been using GVR V1.50 without any problems.

Comment: Yup, it's on a galaxy s6.  Gyro works.

Comment: I would recommend opening Android Monitor and watch the LogCat for StackTrace